Mirror modifier using geometry nodes, supporting arbitrary rotations
My question is very similar to the following question:
Geometry node: mirror position of object
However, the GN I'm using causes a glitch when I apply a rotation.
Is there a way to flip the object left and right while also referencing rotation?
If I rotate the Y axis, it is working as I expect it to:

However, Z and X axis rotation will rotate in ridiculous directions:


I want to create this kind of behavior with Geometry Node:


You'll need to provide more details. "Causes a glitch when I apply a rotation" is not clear. "while also referencing rotation" is not clear. While you're editing your question to precisely describe your problem, your question, and the solution you're looking for, please also edit the title of your question to concisely describe your actual question (not be a general topic).

How about this? Let me know if you still have trouble understanding the question

That's much better details. I've edited the question formatting so the images are shown inline and changed my downvote to an upvote. Hopefully you will now be able to get help from the true experts.

Thanks! I didn't know it could be displayed inline!
